# Package 'kvsetkeys' error Undefined key {family}

Tags: packages, kvoptions

While compiling my document, I am getting the following error message. I updated my packages and especially, `kvsetkeys` and `kvoptions` packages. Kindly guide me how to fix this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[width=1.00cm, height=1.00cm, left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, 
top=2.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym,textcomp,array,arcs,polynom,cancel,enumerate,dcolumn}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=magenta,citecolor=capri]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor = {teal}}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\chapterfont{\color{gray}}
\sectionfont{\color{brown}}
\subsectionfont{\color{blue}}
\paragraphfont{\color{green!50!black}}
\usepackage[most,listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[left]{showlabels}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
 bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am unable to fix this error.

Comment: it is impossible to debug a screenshot (especially of that view which is a notoriously unhelpful summary of the errors by that editor) Please show the actual errors from the log file, and preferably a small complete document  as text, a code block in the question editor (`{}`) so people can see what the issue is

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated my question. I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Your document runs without error (but with a couple of warnings) in both latex and pdflatex if using an up to date texlive 2019.  show your log or at least add `\listfiles` and show the file list that that adds to the end of the log

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My Miktex is up to date. I don't know why am I getting an error message.

Comment: with miktex it is almost always because either the user or admin install is not uptodate you need to update both but without seeing the log impossible to tell which packages you are missing

Comment: you are still showing the editor summary as an image, which gives no information that helps debugging. add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then show the file list as tex

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting you. I included the `\listfiles` to my preamble. Then what to do I am not understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103076/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-sachchidanand-prasad).

Comment: Not exactly, but I removed the `thmtools` and corresponding commands `\declaretheoremstyle` then it started working again.